# Can't get the days difference in momentJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I'm trying to get how many days left till the date, I'm using momentJs, below is the code I'm using but in front end it gives me `Nan` which means error.

```
const start = moment();
  const end = moment(coupon.validTill, 'DD MM YYYY');
  const diff = end.diff(start, "days")
```

coupon.validTill is 30/02/2023
The image below is from my collection in mongodb which shows the validity date

[image]

Comment: _"coupon.validTill is 30/02/2023"_ - then why are you saying that the format you wanted to parse was `DD MM YYYY`?

Comment: Why use a library that has been [depreciated](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/-project-status/00-intro/) for over 2 years for a calculation that can be done with plain JavaScript?  [How to calculate number of days between two dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542938/how-to-calculate-number-of-days-between-two-dates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your validTill date is wrong,
fab month can't have 30 days.
use a valid date and try, it will work fine.